# Recover data after badblock -w?

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I have a disk which Windows would not power on showing me the BSOD.

I inserted a LiveCD to see if there were errors on the disk and there were, so I used the badblocks command as seen on a website tutorial. They said to use it with the `-w` option, and so I did. The scan finished and some number list appeared.

From the [`badblocks`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/badblocks.8.html#options) manpage:

```
-w     Use write-mode test. With this option, badblocks scans for bad blocks by writing
       some patterns (0xaa, 0x55, 0xff, 0x00) on every block of the device, reading every
       block and comparing the contents. This option may not be combined with the -n
       option, as they are mutually exclusive.
```

After that I restarted and the computer was not able to find the disk. I inserted the LiveCD again and looked at GParted and the disk was shown as empty and with no partitions.

As the manual say the `-w` option deletes all data.

Is there any way to recover it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [badblocks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/badblocks.8.html) with option `-w` performs a **write** test on each block of your harddisk. Once it is finished all block will be overwritten by the test data. These data can not be recovered (even forensic tools may fail there).

Only if you had interrupted the write process before it was finished you may have a small chance to recover remnants of your data that have not been overwritten yet.

Option `-w` was designed to test new harddisks where data loss is not an issue for write failures.